Tira al azar da casi siempre el mismo resultado
Tengo este programa en LPP que simula la tirada de un dado. Al tirar el dado consecutivamente, siempre da el mismo resultado, o a veces uno distinto, y no se sé el programa está mal o es un error de LPP
    entero tirada, minimo, maximo
         
inicio
    tirada <- 0
    minimo <- 1
    maximo <- 6
    
    Escriba "Pulse cualquier tecla para lanzar el dado"
    llamar obtener_caracter()
    
    llamar inicializar_aleatorio
       
    Repita
        tirada <- aleatorio()*(maximo + 1)
    Hasta (tirada >= minimo) y (tirada <= maximo)
    
    llamar nueva_linea
    Escriba "El dado cay¢ en el n£mero ", tirada
Fin


El Y en el condicional no está funcionando adecuadamente. El LPP se debe agrupar los condicionales del Y con un paréntesis.
Quedaría así:
repetir
.
.
.
Hasta ((tirada >= minimo) y (tirada <= maximo))


Ok, jaja, encontré algo, que debe ser interesante para el problema que tienes.
En LPP, la función aleatorio() genera un número real entre 0 y 1. Es decir un decimal.
Pero el problema, al parecer, radica en LPP en si mismo.
Me puse a generar 100 números aleatorios, usando la función, y cada vez que ejecuto, genera en el mismo orden, los mismos numeros.
Asi que si, tu idea está bien, pero en LPP, se produce ese error. Lo cual debe ser una limitante de la misma herramienta.
(Por cierto, el decimal, lo puedes pasar a entero, pero siguen generandose siempre en el mismo orden, en mi caso, siempre dio 5, por que el 2do generado era 0.56)


Lo que pasa es que está faltando la "semilla", el cambiador de la secuencia. Lo que pasa es que esa función está ausente en LPP. En código fuente C sería srand (time(NULL));. lo más cercando en LPP sería inicializar_aleatorio

Claro, pero en este caso yo creo que es demostrable una limitación de la herramienta, versus cualquier otro código mas completo. (de todos modos LPP es un proyecto de graduacion de alguien)
